# GTM, Event - Click, Target - Links, GA Events - Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have the following code:

```
<body>
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
    <script>
        (function(w,d,s,l,i){
            w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })
        (window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');
    </script>

    ...
    <a class="filelink" href="files/Client.zip">Client</a>
    ...
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"/> 
</body>
```

I added the following (GTM):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Problem that Events in Google Analystics are empty (including Real-Time). Other functions work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close!

Because you have `Wait for Tags` checked, you'll need to specify on what pages your want your trigger to fire on e.g. `Page URL matches RegEx .*` for all pages (if that's what you want to do), and then put your `Click URL matches RegEx .(7z|zip)$` as your condition in the "Fire On" step.

[image]